# What is the unit for electric flux?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, gauss-law, units, si-units

When I was studying for competitive exams, I was told that the flux is unit of electric flux is V-m or Nm^2/C. But now in my UG I am being told that the unit of electric flux is C. When I the checked internet about the same, many sites including Wikipedia stated that the unit of electric flux is V-m. Will that mean the concepts that I have learnt for my exams are wrong and the  actual idea of flux is different ? If so, what is that  ? please clarify my doubt.

Comment: Please give sources for your statements: which wikipedia article. Note also that the units differ between mksi and cgs.

Comment: Wikipedia link (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_flux). Also, when I checked (https://www.britannica.com/science/electric-flux)  the electric flux is defined as charge divided by epsilon, the same as I learnt in school. However it was also mentioned that in CGS the net flux of an electric field through any closed surface is equal to the constant 4π times the enclosed charge, in electrostatic units (_esu_). I have learnt previously that the unit of epsilon is farad per meter in SI. @Urb said that epsilon is dimensionless according to Lorentz-Heaviside units. Please elaborate.

Comment: @my2cts please clarify my doubt

Comment: As I stated in my answer it depends on whether you use E or D as the electric field. Your sources simply opted for the other choice. The cgs and Heaviside unit systems are just a distraction.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah I think it's from the Electromagnetic Theory subject in 2nd year of engineering. I also had the same doubt. The flux is defined and notated differently in this subject.
Here we use, $\Psi = Q$ (from Gauss' law used in electromagnetic engineering) . Here are some sample text from **Chapter 3, Engineering Electromagnetics by William Hayt,8e**.

Page 49

> Faraday’s experiments also showed, of course, that a larger positive charge on the
> inner sphere induced a correspondingly larger negative charge on the outer sphere,
> leading to a direct proportionality between the electric flux and the charge on the inner
> sphere. The constant of proportionality is dependent on the system of units involved,
> and we are fortunate in our use of SI units, because the constant is unity. If electric
> flux is denoted by  $\Psi$(psi) and the total charge on the inner sphere by Q, then for
> Faraday’s experiment
> $$\boxed{\Psi = Q}$$
> and the electric flux $\Psi$ is measured in coulombs.

---

Page 52

> *The electric flux passing through any closed surface is equal to the total charge enclosed
> by that surface.*

---

Page 53

> We then have the mathematical formulation of Gauss’s law,
> $$\boxed{\Phi = \oint_S \textbf{D}_S \cdot d\textbf{S} = \text{charge enclosed } = Q}$$

(where $\textbf{D}_S$ is the electric flux density on the surface over which the integral is evaluated)

In schools and in general we use $\phi = \frac Q{\varepsilon_0}$(Gauss' law) .
So both are equivalent but are scaled by a constant $\varepsilon_0$ . Now the units vary  because $\varepsilon$ is a constant with dimensions $\rm{C^2m^{-2}N^{-1}}$ and    $\Psi$ has $\boxed{\text{units of }(\phi\times \varepsilon_0) = \rm{C^{-1}Nm^2}\times\rm{C^2m^{-2}N^{-1}} = C}$.

Comment: Please type out relevant parts of text rather than posting images. Images are not accessible to all users.

Comment: Yeah sure, I thought adding directly from book will do. Didn't realize all couldn't access images. Thanks, I'm editing

Answer (score 1):

In mksi units the unit of electric flux is Vm. In cgs units it is $esu$.

**However**, if you define electric flux based on $D=\epsilon_0 \epsilon E$ in place of $E$ then the unit is $C$.

The confusion arises because of these two different definitions of electric flux.

Comment: I have known _esu_ as unit of electric charge in CGS system. How did the unit of flux which is V-m in SI system be unit of charge in CGS ? Also, I would like to know elaborately about the two different definitions of electric flux and when to use what.

Answer (score 1):

OP is probably mixing unit systems.

In SI units, the permittivity $\varepsilon_0$ has units of $\rm F/m=C/(V\cdot m)$ and electric flux then

$${\Phi}=\int{\bf E}\cdot{\bf dS}\sim\frac{Q}{\varepsilon_0}\to\frac{\rm C}{\displaystyle\rm \frac{C}{V\ m}}=\rm V\  m.$$

In the often used [Lorentz-Heaviside units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz%E2%80%93Heaviside_units), $\varepsilon_0=1$ is dimensionless, and $\Phi\sim Q$.

Comment: In th e Lorentz_Heaviside units the charge unit is not the Coulomb (C).

Comment: You're right, electric flux and charge just have the same units.